# Solving $Ax_2 = \lambda x_1$ and $A^Tx_1 = \lambda x_2$ using SVD

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Please using only SVD, I have solved the problem using other methods
Solving $Ax_2 = \lambda x_1$ and $A^Tx_1 = \lambda x_2$ using SVD:
I am solving this to find $\lambda$ and $x_1,x_2$

To find $x_2$ I rearranged the above and got $A^TAx_2 = \lambda^2 x_2$ and letting $A = U \Sigma V^T$ I get the $A^TA = V\Sigma ^T \Sigma V^T = V\Lambda V^{-1}$ since $V$ is unitary . Hence the eigenvectors are the columns of $V$ which are $v_j$, i.e. $x_2 = v_j$ and $\lambda = \pm \sigma_j$ were $\sigma_j$ are the  of $A$.

Now doing the same trick to find $x_1$ I have that $AA^Tx_1 = \lambda ^2 x_1$ so $AA^T = U \Lambda U^{-1}$ by using the SVD decomposition, hence again $x_1 = u_j$ and $\lambda = \pm \sigma_j$ however the solutions are:

$x_1 = u_j, x_2 = v_j, $ and $ \lambda = \sigma_j$

$x_1 = -u_j, x_2 = v_j, $ and $ \lambda = -\sigma_j$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagonalization of the symmetric matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
0&A\\
A^T&0
\end{bmatrix}
via tridiagonalization per Hessenberg-form and then a very optimized application of the QR algorithm
is the basic idea of the Golub-Kahan method to compute the SVD of the matrix $A$. So essentially the task asks you to compute the SVD by computing the SVD.

If you have computed $A=UΣV^T$ then any vector $v_j$ of the columns of $V$ satisfies
$$
Av_j=\sigma_j u_j\text{ and in reverse }A^T u_j=\sigma_j v_j
$$
which is exactly what the task asks of you.

By simultaneously changing the sign of $u_j$ and $σ_j$ you get the modification
$$
Av_j=(-\sigma_j) (-u_j)\text{ and in reverse }A^T (-u_j)=(-\sigma_j) v_j
$$
and indeed $-σ_j$ is also an eigenvalue of the block matrix above, for each singular value $σ_j$ of $A$, the block matrix has the pair $-σ_j,σ_j$ as eigenvalues, with the eigenvectors $\binom{-u_j}{v_j}$ and $\binom{u_j}{v_j}$.

Comment: From my workings, I found that $x_1 = u_j$, I'm still not sure how you managed to get $-u_j$ from that

Comment: You can also leave the sign on $u_j$ and change both the signs on $σ_j$ and $v_j$, i.e., $x_1=u_j$, $x_2=-v_j$ and $λ=−σ_j$. In the end, you can change any eigenvector by a non-zero factor without changing the property of being an eigenvector. So $\binom{u_j}{-v_j}$ is in the same eigenspace as $\binom{-u_j}{v_j}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean, my working to find $x_1 = u_j$ was that wrong? I hoped I would find $x_1 = -u_j$

Comment: You were at the step where $x_2=v_j$ and $λ=±σ_j$. Now evaluate $λx_1=Ax_2=σ_ju_j$ to get $x_1=±u_j$.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't see how evaluationg $\lambda x_1 = Ax_2$ would yield $x_1 = \pm u_j$ could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm assuming you made a mistake you wrote "$Ax_2 = \sigma_j u_j$" but I'm not sure how you found $x_1$ at all without doing the SVD like I did. Using that SVD I get $x_1$ as $u_j$ did I apply it wrongly?

Comment: OK,  longer form, starting from your partial solution at the indicated step: $$±σ_jx_1=λx_1=Ax_2=Av_j=UΣV^Tv_j=UΣe_j=σ_jUe_j=σ_ju_j$$ which implies from first to last $x_1=±u_j$.